# What is the meaning behind the silent dream scene in Battle Royale?

Tags: analysis, battle-royale

Sometime after the Battle Royale started, either Kitano or Noriko (not entirely sure) have a dream. They are both walking casually by a river, eating popsicles, and talking to each other. We do not hear what is being said.

[image]

Is this a dream or a flashback of some sort? And what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to set up their relationship in the film. I haven't watched the film in a very long while, so I looked at the Wikipedia article that lists and explains the characters and their relationships, and it appears to [confirm it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Battle_Royale_characters#Noriko_Nakagawa)

It is most likely a flashback seeing as their relationship exists in the film and is not just a fantasy.